# mypage.aspx.designer.cs is not generating the code

Tags: c#, asp.net

i'm merging the code from previous mypage.aspx to new branch mypage.aspx. 
i also change the mypage.aspx.cs file. But mypage.aspx.designer.cs file not generate the code.

i delete some code from mypage.aspx.designer.cs accidentally.

Now it show error on mypage.aspx.cs file.

**ERROR :** The name does not exist in the current context

**I TRIED**

Clean And Rebuild

**FYI**  I cant Delete the File. i cant add any new file. Like delete the file create the file in Same Name Like that.

Please Help me to fix the issue.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometime just saving the **ASPX** file <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> solves the problem.

The worst case you can delete designer.cs, and recreate it by using **Convert to Web Application**.

***Note***: it'll only convert individual designer.cs (not entire application).

### Visual Studio 2012

[image]

### Updated for Visual Studio 2013

In VS 2013, **Convert to Web Application** is moved under **Project.**

[image]