# Visual Studio 2015 ASP.NET Can't access Control ID in code behind. Won't build

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015, webforms

This is specifically for Visual Studio 2015.

In my Site.master I have

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="~/Site.master.cs" Inherits="SiteMaster" %>

<asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server" />
```

And in my Site.master.cs I have

```
Literal1.Text = "test";
```

In addition in Site.master.cs I have

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using WebMatrix.Data;


public partial class SiteMaster : MasterPage
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Literal1.Text = "test";
    }
```

And it won't build. I get the error:

> error CS0103: The name 'Literal1' does not exist in the current context.

There is no designer file. I don't know how to get the designer file back for VS2015. I've tried several older suggestions from previous versions of VS.
I'd like to get it to build whether I need a designer file or not.

Comment: Is it a web site project? Or a web application project? Did you manually remove a designer file? Are you using source code control?

Comment: I'm using git source control. On my menu it says "Website," not project.

Comment: In a website project, there would be no designer files. You probably need to show the @Page directive at the top of your ASPX and show the code for your class in your question.

Comment: Ok, thanks. What's the difference between the website project and a web application project? Since it is a Master page it shows <%@ Master instead of <%@ Page

Comment: Right, then include the @Master directive in your question. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398037/asp-net-web-site-or-asp-net-web-application) for the difference.

Comment: Ok, I edited with @master. Any solution?

Comment: You need to show the entire @Master directive in your question, and the corresponding class from your code behind.

Comment: Is your Literal inside any other templated control, like a Repeater or GridView? Are other controls you reference by ID working?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133658/discussion-between-josh-ginn-and-mason).

Comment: No, it's just surrounded by html. A div tag

Comment: @JoshGinn Could you change `CodeFile="~/Site.master.cs"` to `CodeBehind="Site.master.cs"` and see it makes any different?

Comment: Thanks, @Win. I've tried that. It doesn't work.

Comment: @JoshGinn Are you developing a new application or are you migrating old one to VS 2015?

Comment: I started out with a new application. The <asp: controls work on the pages but not on this master file specifically.

Comment: @JoshGinn Could you show the steps how you create that ASP.Net Web Form Application? I'm curious why you have WebMatrix in your project. [WebMatrix](https://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/) was replaced by Visual Studio Code.

Comment: It's something we brought in for a data connection from an older project. However, I did create the project from scratch as a new VS2015 Web Forms application first.

Comment: File> New Project > Web > ASP.NET Web Application > Web Forms

Comment: @JoshGinn In that case, since it's a Project and not a Site, you should be using CodeBehind (instead of CodeFile) and you should have designer files. You can delete the page and recreate it and the system should create a designer file for you.

Comment: @JoshGinn mason is correct. If you want to know how to regenerate designer, look at [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38103284/296861).

Comment: I don't have that option.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean and rebuild your project obviously when the project is not running. Sometimes when your project is running visual studio cannot generate designer files properly. Try change the label Id or remove and re-insert it.

Comment: I've tried rebuilding. It didn't work. What method do you use to clean?

Comment: Right-click on project or solution and choose the click menu.

Comment: Yeah, that says Build or Rebuild, but not clean.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this error I created a new master page. I deleted everything below the header and pasted everything below the header from the original (not including the original's header.)

Also, in the code behind I did not delete the class, but instead pasted the original functions into the new class.

Then on the pages that use the old master page I changed them to use the new master page.